# Mimic Windows's Remote Desktop dual display on Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xorg, vnc

I have a computer which was running Windows 7 Ultimate. I used this computer over a remote desktop connection. The setup was the following: the computer which had the remote desktop connection enabled (from now on referred as server) had one VGA port with a monitor connected but usually turned off. The computer I used to remotely control the server (client from now on) had two monitors. When I connected to the server with my client PC I had an option to use all of my screens I.E. to get a second desktop even though the server had one monitor connected. Both of the monitors have 1024x768 resolution.

Recently I installed Xubuntu on the server machine and I tried to achieve the same but it didn't work as I expected.

If I list the display connectors on the server with xrandr it gives a VGA and a DVI port but only the VGA is populated and I don't have any cable/adapter for the DVI.

What I have tried so far:

- install x11vnc and run (this worked but I had only one desktop)
- run xrandr --fb 2048x768 & x11vnc --clip 1024x768+1024+0 (resulted only in a black screen at the client end)

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

The client runs Windows XP and I tried to connect with ThightVNC, RealVNC with the same results. I don't necessarily have to use XP on the client machine, I can install Xubuntu there too, but I can't install Ubuntu because none of these machines have decent enough graphics card to run Unity.